# Does bashing open a container damage it's contents?

Tags: star-wars-kotor

It's been a while since I've run a character without at least some token Security skill. I know that there are no consequences to bashing open doors, but I can't remember what the deal is with containers. If I smash the locks (or delicately slice them open with a Lightsaber), will the items I receive be reduced/damaged/altered in any way?

Comment: I know that in kotor2, bashing things open gives you less stuff.  I don't remember if that was the case in kotor1

Answer (score 3):

In the [Gamespot Guide](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/star-wars-knights-of-the-old-republic-ii-the-sith-lords-walkthrough/1100-6115513/) for KOTOR 2 it mentions:

> Unlike in KOTOR, though, bashing containers in KOTOR2 will often break items inside, leaving you with piles of junk where you might’ve obtained something terrifically useful had you the acumen required to open the chest. For this reason alone, it’s usually worthwhile to have someone in your party with a good Security skill.

This leads me to believe you can bash away without consequence in the first game.

Answer (score -1):

I encourage you to test this yourself by using security on a chest and then reloading the save right before that, then bashing it open. It seems to not actually break any items, instead it just adds “broken item” which can then be broken down into components. 
Bash away!